# Why Nullable<int> can't compile but int? does without 'using System;'

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction

In .Net 2, the code:

```
namespace ns
{
    class Class1
    {
        Nullable<int> a;
    }
}
```

does not compile and gives the error:

> The type or namespace name 'Nullable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It is missing `using System;` but this code:

```
namespace ns
{
    class Class1
    {
        int? a;
    }
}
```

compiles.

Can somebody explain why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that int? is an alias for

```
System.Nullable<System.Int32>
```

Because the full type name is specified, there are no reason to add a `using` directive.

Answer (score 11):

The `T?` syntax is translated by the compiler into `System.Nullable<T>` by referencing the type directly, rather than by examining the `using`s that are in scope. You could similarly write this and the compiler would succeed:

```
System.Nullable<int> a;
```

Answer (score 2):

? is a language construct, while System.Nullable is a class - since it lives in the System namespace, you have to import it in the file (or more often, explicitly import it for the whole project as part of the project properties/configuration).

Answer (score 0):

`int` is an alias for `System.Int32`. That's why it doesn't need to be prefixed with its namespace.

But `Nullable` is not. It's need its fully qualified name.