# The type or namespace name 'nullable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, namespaces

In a C# file when I try to run the file, Am getting the above error.
Probably, I must have deleted the namespace by mistake and am not able to find it now.
Kindly let me know what is the namespace to be used for nullable type.

Comment: What file ? Can you post some code ? Is it a ASP.NET MVC 4 app ?

Comment: Could be `Nullable` instead? Please show your work first.. It's clearly you are missing a `using directive` that your type belongs or you are missing an assembly in your project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Nullable<int> can't compile but int? does without 'using System;'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371334/why-nullableint-cant-compile-but-int-does-without-using-system)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Point your cursor to the `Nullable` then press `Ctrl`+`.`.

BTW its `using System;`

Answer (score 1):

Either use `using System;` at the top of your class or instead of 'nullable' , use `System.Nullable`.

Better is to use `using System;`